# Create a "bridge" between eth1 and tun0

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, vpn, ethernet, openvpn

I'm trying to access remotely a device (in this case a PLC) through a 3G/4G internet connection.
I have a Raspberry PI connect to the internet with a 3G modem and a OpenVPN configured on it.
The eth0 port is connected to the 3G/4G modem and the eth1 port is connected to the PLC.

How do I add the eth1 port to the VPN connection so I can access the PLC trough any computer connected to this VPN?

This images may better explain what I'm tryng to achive:
[physical connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUP6U.png)
[virtual connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5G4d.png)